# Expanding DIV based on contents

Tags: html, css, dynamic

I currently have a few divs nested within each other to display my content. The two inner divs should expand equally in height based on the text displayed inside of them but currently the text just keeps going without the DIV.

From reading other user's questions, it was recommended to use overflow: auto; but this resulted in scrollbars, where I actually want the height of the divs to grow if needed. Currently the container DIV has a fixed height which I have tried changing to min-height instead, however this causes it to be much taller than the actual contents inside which I believe is caused by them have 100% height.

How can this be fixed?

[image]

```
.item
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #5ea8de;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.trigger
{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #5ea8de;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 15px;
    border: 2px solid green;
}
.task
{
    width: 78%;
    height: 90%;
    margin-top: 7px;
    background-color: #1c3c5b;
    float: left;
    /*border: 1px solid;*/
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
        foreach ($tasks as $task)
        {
            echo "<div class='item'>";

            $id = $task->Id;
            $type = $task->Type;
            $desc = $task->Description;
            $emits = $task->Emits;
            $events = $task->Tasks;

            echo "<div class='trigger'>
                    <div class='remove'><a href=''><img src='images/remove.png'></a></div>
                    <h4>Trigger: </h4></br>
                    $desc
                    <p>
                    <h4>Emits: </h4>";

                foreach ($emits as $emit)
                {
                    echo $emit . "</br>";
                }

                echo "</div>";
                echo "<div class='task'>";

                    foreach($events as $event)
                    {
                        $event_id = $event->Id;
                        $event_method = $event->TaskMethodName;
                        $event_params = $event->ParameterMapping;
                        $event_oneshot = $event->IsOneshot;
                        $event_enabled = $event->Enabled;

                        // Use the Method ID and retrieve Description for display (Make helper method for this???)
                        foreach ($methods as $method)
                        {
                            if ($method->Id == $event_method)
                            {
                                echo "<div class='remove'><a href=''><img src='images/remove.png'></a></div>";
                                echo "<h4>METHOD: " . $method->Description . "</h4>";
                            }
                        }

                        // Loop through the individual parameters and display both the key/value
                        foreach ($event_params as $key => $value)
                        {
                            echo "<label>" . $key . " | " . $value . "</label></br>";
                        }

                        echo "<hr>";
                    }

                echo "</div>"; //Task

            echo "</div>"; //Trigger
        }
```

Comment: Where is your html? It sounds like this can be done by using `display: table` Something like http://jsfiddle.net/uLbevpaj/

Comment: I just updated the original post with the HTML as well

Comment: See my fiddle in my updated comment

Comment: This is absolutely perfect for the task that was overflowing, thank you! One question though, the second listing has much less text and is now not filling the same height it was previously even with height: 100% set. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: By second list I assume you mean another row under the first one, the height will be based on the content so yes each row will have different heights

Comment: The red area in this image is what I am referring to. There is no way to make the height fill the red scribble area? http://i.imgur.com/38avSO4.png Would you like to post your answer so I can accept it? Thanks :)

Comment: Actually that part should be filled. If it is not then there is some css interfering with it. You probably have float on the blue area which will cause it to not extend. If you look at the css carefully, there is no float in my example

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. I removed the float from both elements and it worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using `display: table` Here is an example

http://jsfiddle.net/uLbevpaj/

```
.item {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #5ea8de;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    display: table;
}
.trigger {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #5ea8de;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-left: 15px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    display: table-cell;
}
.task {
    width: 78%;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 7px;
    background-color: #1c3c5b;
    display: table-cell;
    /*border: 1px solid;*/
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adjusting the item class to use `min-height` and adding `overflow:hidden` as I've done in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/uLbevpaj/2/) for you :)
This should allow it to maintain a minimum size as you've mentioned while still growing dynamically with the text.

```
.item{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color: #5ea8de;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```